# Interface Builder: Enabled1,2 property with OR operator

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I need to set the property Enabled of a control in interface builder, depending on 2 booleans int he preferences.

However the operator should be OR and not AND. If one of the two is true, than my control should be enabled.

Currently, I can only make it work with an AND operator, (See screenshot).

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, in IB, you're stuck with and.   My suggestion would be to add a new property to an object accessible to your NIB (possibly your owner for the NIB), which is dependent on changes to the other objects in order to enable your control/view.

It looks like you're using the `Shared User Defaults Controller`, so I would suggest that in the owner you create a new boolean property for your combined user defaults (perhaps `downloadingCastOrCrew`), and then you'll need to make sure that when either of the defaults change, you change the value of `downloadingCastOrCrew`:

In your Interface:

```
@property BOOL downloadingCastOrCrew;
```

In the implementation as you're setting up your controller or after awakeFromNib:

```
 [[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] addObserver:self
      forKeyPath: @"values.kSearchPreferencesDownloadCast"
      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
      context:NULL];
 [[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] addObserver:self
      forKeyPath: @"values.kSearchPreferencesDownloadCrew"
      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
      context:NULL];
```

In the implementation as you're tearing down your controller:
     [[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] removeObserver: self
          forKeyPath: @"values.kSearchPreferencesDownloadCast"];

```
 [[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] removeObserver: self
      forKeyPath: @"values.kSearchPreferencesDownloadCrew"];
```

Add an observer if you don't already have one:

```
 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object 
      change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
 {
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     self.downloadingCastOrCrew = [defaults boolForKey: @"kSearchPreferencesDownloadCast"] 
         || [defaults boolForKey: @"kSearchPreferencesDownloadCrew"];
 }
```

By using the accessor method, you'll trigger kvo and you'll be able to use the controller's `downloadingCastOrCrew` as your boolean to check instead of the NSUserDefaults values directly.

Obviously, if you already have an observeValueForKeyPath, you will likely want to add a context value to the `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context` call and check it in the `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way :

Create a third property

```
@property BOOL isFirst;
@property BOOL isSecond;

@property BOOL isTextFieldVisible;//this one is your third

- (IBAction)isSec:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)isFir:(id)sender;
```

In implementation

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.isFirst=NO;
        self.isSecond=NO;
    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)isSec:(id)sender {
    self.isSecond=!self.isSecond;
    [sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"isSecond: %d",self.isSecond]];

    self.isTextFieldVisible=self.isFirst || self.isSecond;

    self.isTextFieldVisible=!self.isTextFieldVisible;

    NSLog(@"->%d",self.isTextFieldVisible);
}

- (IBAction)isFir:(id)sender {
    self.isFirst=!self.isFirst;
    [sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"isfirst: %d",self.isFirst]];

    self.isTextFieldVisible=self.isFirst || self.isSecond;

     self.isTextFieldVisible=!self.isTextFieldVisible;

    NSLog(@"->%d",self.isTextFieldVisible);
}
@end
```

And in the binding just bind the textField to third property,

Check the running application [here](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/6020465/bindingwithtwovaluesoring-34k?da=y).

EDIT 1:

Change  ValueTransformer `NSNegateBoolean` in IB. so that my two lines `self.isTextFieldVisible=!self.isTextFieldVisible;` is not required in both the IBAction.

Comment: Why do you set `isTextFieldVisible` to the negation of itself after setting it to the OR expression that the questioner wanted?

Comment: @PeterHosey: I wasn't able to show for True value of BOOl, then I tried with False value then it worked. the project is attached here, if you can check.

Comment: @PeterHosey: I got a good solution, I need to use ValueTransformer `NSNegateBoolean` in IB. so that my two lines `self.isTextFieldVisible=!self.isTextFieldVisible;` is not required.